# css mobile view is not working

Tags: html, css

In my css project I have :

body with left section,right section and a footer..I want when I go to mobile view The display should be

```
left section
right section
footer
```

but here what I have tried,I am getting

```
left section,
right section ----->>this section overrides to footer..
footer
```

jsfiddle is:

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/m7nmvf7t/)
what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `height` from `.container` and set it `overflow: hidden`, of course also close the `<p>` tag as Tushar said.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    font-family:'Cabin', sans-serif;
}
.contanier {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
    flex: 3 1 60%;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    /*height: 1500px;*/  /*removed*/
    overflow: hidden;    /*added*/
}
#rightcol {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    background:green;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
    flex: 1 6 20%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
#content {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 68%;
    height: 1500px;
    -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
    flex: 1 6 20%;
    -webkit-order: 3;
    order: 3;
}
#registration-form {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}
#registration-form .fieldset {
    /* background-color:#fc9a24; */
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#registration-form legend {
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    color: white;
    font-size:2em;
}
.fields box {
    border:3px solid #fc9a24;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    padding:30px 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}
#footer {
    display: block;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #eebb55;
    border-radius: 7pt;
    background: #ffeebb;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #rightcol, #content {
        display:block!important;
        width:100%;
    }
    .contanier, footer {
        -webkit-flex-flow: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #rightcol, #content {
        /* Return them to document order */
        -webkit-order: 0;
        order: 0;
    }
    #rightcol {
        min-height: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="contanier">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Content Section
                <p>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcol">
            <div id="registration-form">
                <div class='fields'>
                    <legend>basic info</legend>
                    <div class='box'>
                        <div class='row'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>footer</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

[**Here a working jsfiddle example to play with**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/m7nmvf7t/1/)

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is:

- Remove  `max-height: 50px` from `#rightcol` in `@media` query
- You have unclosed `<p>` tag, remember to close the same by `</p>`

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cd3pst3a/4/)**

Comment: sorry sir, I have updated the link..previously I was forgot to update the whole container.Now I have updated the link

Comment: previously I was forgot to update the whole container. this is the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/m7nmvf7t/